# How can I deploy a release with multiple artifacts

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 CI builds. One is responsible for building an WebAPI project, the second builds a node application. Both builds produce an artifact.

I want to encapsulate both of these builds into a single continuous deployment release.

From what I can see, you can only add one release trigger that fires when one (the primary) artifact changes.

Is there a way to add multiple triggers to the release definition? So when either build is run and the artifacts are produced, that single release is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build definitions currently only support a single trigger.

A possible workaround for the time being might be to trigger the release definition from a build task in either build definition through [Visual Studio Team Services REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release).

Comment: Thanks, I think that workaround will suffice until there is a better mechanism. Do you know if there is a work item to add multiple triggers?

Comment: I assume Microsoft has it on their backlog. But to be sure you can add it to their [UserVoice page](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services),